# Azure Logic App blob added or modified trigger not working correctly when app is cloned

Tags: triggers, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have a Azure blobstorage with 3 different containers, lets call them `container-a`, `container-b` and `container-c` where more or less frequently data is uploaded as txt files.
I then created a logic app with `When a blob is added or modified` trigger and connected it to to `container-a` - worked like a charme.
So i cloned the LogicApp and then connected them with the according blobs `container-b` or rather `container-c`, but the trigger is fired with blobs which were added to `container-a` in both clones.
I checked all the Triggers settings, but everything looks quite okay to me.

FYI:
I edited the question, since it only seemed to occur with my *cloned* Logic Apps using that trigger.
I have to proof if i can recap the issue

Comment: Could you please give a screenshot of the blob trigger of the azure logic app.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error - it is definitely a bug:

1. When selecting a new container for an existing blobstorage
   connection, this container is saved, but in the background (to be
   checked in the `Logic app code view` option under `definition -> triggers -> metadata`) this container is created incorrectly -
   because twice.
   This apparently seems to result in simply using the first
   container (in an alphanumeric order) of the connected blobstorage.
2. Deleting this duplicate entry mentioned above in the code view did something for me in one case, but not in the other.
   In the end, the best thing to do is to
   completely reconnect the blobstorage in the Trigger step of the ´Logic Apps Designer` and then select the desired container there again.